# WEB API httpException is not caught

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a WEB API application, where we add some session verification logic and then call base SendAsync method after that.

When we pass request containing byte[] larger than 4MB line `response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);` throws a httpException "maximum request length exceeded", which is ok and can be managed through IIS settings. What bothers me is that next step - it's still calling controller method, where I can see that this byte[] parameter set to null. Controller method throws ArgumentNullException and this what end user gets.

First of all I can't understand why controller method still gets called after HttpException. And more important how can I manage to catch this HttpException, so that end user will see actual reason, why the request was not processed.
Thank you in advance.

```
public class SessionIdHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //some additional logic here
        HttpResponseMessage response;
        try
        {
            response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(e.Message, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
            };
        }
        finally
        {
            if (signedOnHere)
            {
                Signoff(sessionId);
            }
        }
        return response;
   }
}
```

Comment: What's this controller method you are mentioning? Is it `Signoff(sessionId)?`

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstood, isn't this just default `try catch finally` behaviour?

Comment: No, controller method is not called from the code above directly. It is AddDocument method, which is described in request and just being intercepted by the code above for a while in order to check session.

Comment: @mattytommo, how do you mean default behaviour? As I'm not mistaken Tasks usually throw AggreagteException. Here I have two exceptions thrown from call to base.SendAsync method and I get only last of them. I would expect either one but Aggregate or one which happens first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What bothers me is that next step - it's still calling controller
>   method, where I can see that this byte[] parameter set to null.

When you call `base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);`, you're effectively continuing the WebAPI pipeline, which will eventually results in the controller getting invoked:

[image: WebAPI pipeline]

What you actually want is to check the `Content-Length` header before you even send the request to the controller. You do so by retrieving it for the header of the request. If the size exceeds, you can return a response indicating that, otherwise, continue the pipeline:

```
protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
            HttpRequestMessage request, 
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // 4MB, perhaps you want to loosen this up a bit as other request
    // characteristics will effect the size.
    const int maxRequestSize = 4194304;

    IEnumerable<string> contentLengthHeader;
    request.Headers.TryGetValues("Content-Length", out contentLengthHeader);

    var contentLength = contentLengthHeader.FirstOrDefault();
    if (contentLength == null)
    {
        //No content-length sent, decide what to do.
    }

    long actualContentlength;
    if (!long.TryParse(contentLength, out actualContentlength))
    {
        // Couldn't parse, decide what to do.
    }

    if (actualContentlength > maxRequestSize)
    {
        // If reached, the content-length of the request was too big. 
        // Return an error response:
        return Task.FromResult(request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden,
            string.Format("Request size exceeded {0} bytes", maxRequestSize)));
    }
    return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
}
```

If you don't want this check for all the controllers in your WebAPI application, you can [pre-route each `DelegatingHandler`](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers).

Comment: Thank you, @Yuval Itzchakov, but I don't want to duplicate logic by checking request length, when it is being check for me by .NET code somewhere behind the scenes. Furthermore, if I use constant const int maxRequestSize = 4194304; and then someone changes IIS settings, it will lead to incorrect behaviour.

Comment: @Olga This was just for the purpose of demonstration. You can read this from the settings of the IIS config if you'd like.

Comment: OK, but anyway it will be duplicating logic. Well, I will do this eventually, I think, if nothing else appears. Thank you!